# cannot figure out why my letters are not rotating in the Caesar code in Python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I have been working on this problem for about a week now and cannot figure out why my letters are not rotating. I am NOT looking for someone to do the code for me but rather help me figure out where my problems are. Basically, I am looking for a rubber duck to help with this problem. I have seen it rotate the last letter but not the rest of the letters. Here is where I am at right now.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase

def caeser_encrypt(string, step):
    new_string = list(string)

    for i in range(len(new_string)):
        new_ascii = ord(new_string[i]) + step

    if string[i] in ascii_uppercase:
        if new_ascii > 90:
            new_ascii = new_ascii - 90 + 64
        elif new_ascii < 65:
            new_ascii = 91 - 65 - new_ascii

    if string[i] in ascii_lowercase:
        if new_ascii > 122:
            new_ascii = new_ascii - 122 + 96
        elif new_ascii < 97:
            new_ascii = 123 - 97 - new_ascii
        new_string[i] = chr(new_ascii)

    return ''.join(new_string)

def main ():
    string = input('Enter word(s)')
    step = input("How many rotations do you want?")
    step = int(step)

    print(caeser_encrypt(string, step))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There seems to be a simple indentation error in your code. Try indenting both the if statements 1 more block. (get them inside the scope of the for loop with the loop variable i. Also, the assignment to new_string[i] should be at the same scope as the if statements, and not inside one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last letter is rotated, because of this indentation:

> ```
> for i in range(len(new_string)):
>     new_ascii = ord(new_string[i]) + step
>
> if string[i] in ascii_uppercase:
>     if new_ascii > 90:
>         new_ascii = new_ascii - 90 + 64
>     elif new_ascii < 65:
>         new_ascii = 91 - 65 - new_ascii
> ```

What you intended is this:

```
for i in range(len(new_string)):
    new_ascii = ord(new_string[i]) + step

    if string[i] in ascii_uppercase:
        if new_ascii > 90:
            new_ascii = new_ascii - 90 + 64
        elif new_ascii < 65:
            new_ascii = 91 - 65 - new_ascii
```

That is, the `if` statements should be indented under the `for` statement.
If the `if` statements are not indented like that,
then they are not executed in a loop,
but executed only once, *after* the `for` loop.
At that time `i` is set to the index of the last letter,
that's why only the last letter is rotated.

#### Code review

Many other improvements are possible.

Instead of magic numbers like 90, 65,
it would be better to use `ord('z')` and `ord('a')`.

The `if string[i] in ascii_uppercase` and `if string[i] in ascii_lowercase` are mutually exclusive conditions,
so they should be chained together with `elif`.

Instead of `if string[i] in ascii_uppercase`,
which performs a linear search in `ascii_uppercase` (checks each value in `ascii_uppercase` until it finds a match),
it would be more efficient to use a range check,
`if 'A' <= string[i] <= 'Z'`.

The implementation replaces non-alphabetic characters too.
If I want to rotate "hello world",
that will give a funny result,
because of the space.
Maybe that's ok like that though,
so that word boundaries remain indistinguishable.
So that's not a criticism, just a side note.

Putting it together,
and some other minor improvements,
you can write like this:

```
def caeser_encrypt(string, step):
    new_string = list(string)

    for i, c in enumerate(new_string):
        new_ascii = ord(c) + step

        if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
            new_ascii = ord('A') + (new_ascii - ord('A')) % 26

        elif 'a' <= c <= 'z':
            new_ascii = ord('a') + (new_ascii - ord('a')) % 26

        new_string[i] = chr(new_ascii)

    return ''.join(new_string)
```

Comment: Y'all THANK YOU SO MUCH! I completely missed the indent.

Comment: @kcbusymom I went a bit further and added some extra tips, see the Code review section.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the extra tips. Gonna go ahead and add those to my notebook for future reference. lol

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of indentation problems there:

1. The `for i in range(len(new_string)):` loop only has one thing happening in it, which is setting `new_ascii`. When that loop finishes, `i` is equal to `len(new_string) - 1`, so it'll set the last character, but not any of the other ones.
2. The `new_string[i] = chr(new_ascii)` line is where your code adds letters to the new string, but check your indentation - it's only happening when `if string[i] in ascii_lowercase:` is true, so only for lowercase letters.

This should work:

```
def caeser_encrypt(string, step):
    new_string = list(string)

    for i in range(len(new_string)):
        new_ascii = ord(new_string[i]) + step

        if string[i] in ascii_uppercase:
            if new_ascii > 90:
                new_ascii = new_ascii - 90 + 64
            elif new_ascii < 65:
                new_ascii = 91 - 65 - new_ascii

        if string[i] in ascii_lowercase:
            if new_ascii > 122:
                new_ascii = new_ascii - 122 + 96
            elif new_ascii < 97:
                new_ascii = 123 - 97 - new_ascii

        new_string[i] = chr(new_ascii)

    return ''.join(new_string)
```

Comment: God bless you! I was seriously going insane looking for my dang bug. I knew it HAD to be something basic but I just could not find it for the life of me.